# Looking for PHP memory/CPU graph generator

Tags: linux, memory, debian, php, charts

Basically, that's what I'm looking for. I want an app that makes a live graph of the server's CPU and RAM usage. Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [ORCA](http://www.orcaware.com/orca/):

> Orca is a tool useful for plotting arbitrary data from text files onto
>   a directory on a Web server.

[image]

- Configuration file based.
- Reads white space separated data files.
- Watches data files for updates and sleeps between reads.
- Finds new files at specified times.
- Remembers the last modification times for files so they do not have to
  be reread continuously.
- Can plot the same type of data from different files into different
  or the same PNGs.
- Different plots can be created based on the filename.
- Parses the date from the text files.
- Create arbitrary plots of data from different columns.
- Ignore columns or use the same column in many plots.
- Add or remove columns from plots without having to deleting RRDs.
- Plot the results of arbitrary Perl expressions, including mathematical
  ones, using one or more columns.
- Group multiple columns into a single plot using regular expressions on
  the column titles.
- Creates an HTML tree of HTML files and PNG plots.
- Creates an index of URL links listing all available targets.
- Creates an index of URL links listing all different plot types.
- No separate CGI set up required.
- Can be run under cron or it can sleep itself waiting for file updates
  based on when the file was last updated.

Answer (score 1):

Munin will do it. Install munin-node on each machine you want to monitor, and setup a Munin server instance to collect and graph all the data.